# keep bootstrap navigation mobile with amp page

Tags: jquery, navigation, amp-html

I like to have the same navigation menu (bootstrap) with AMP pages as with my non AMP pages. I have tried to find solutions on the internet, thinking somebody must have had the same idea as I, but I couldn't find any answer or even close.
AMP is offering a side menu navigation, but I would like to have the top navigation (bootstrap), so it is no different from my non AMP pages on my website.
I tried to use the amp-script component with jquery and custom bootstrap file minimised into 1 js file, not exceeding the 150KB, also I tried them separately with the amp-script component.

`<script async custom-element="amp-script" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-script-0.1.js"></script>
</head><body><amp-script layout="container" src="amp-custom.js"></amp-script>`

The second:

```
<script async custom-element="amp-script" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-script-0.1.js"></script></head><body><amp-script layout="container" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></amp-script><amp-script layout="container" src="js/bootstrap.js"></amp-script>
```

Also tried with https paths from my site and CDN paths, no avail.
The code validates, but when I try to click the menu button for showing the navigation menu nothing happens.
I know I am doing something wrong, but I have no clue to what I am doing wrong.
If there is no solution to this then I have to use the AMP side navigation, which I don't really want.
Any suggestions

Comment: @Vadim, if you could edit, any chance that you have suggestions

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea, this is not relevant to me